# Centering of vdots in a set of aligned equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I wish to center the 3 vertical dots and align this equation but am not able to do so in the below code.
How shall I do it?

```
\begin{multline}
%\begin{center}
\dot{x}=x_1 \\
\dot{x_1}=x_2 \\
\vdots \\
\dot{x_n}= -\frac{f_0}{f_n}x_1  -\frac{f_1}{f_n}x_2- \cdots -\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}x_n
%\end{center}
\end{multline}
```

Comment: Can you please give the complete code how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mathtools` (an extension to `amsmath`) provides a macro for this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= x_1 \\
\dot{x}_1 & =x_2 \\
&\vdotswithin{=} \\
\MTFlushSpaceAbove
\dot{x}_n& = -\frac{f_0}{f_n} x_1  -\frac{f_1}{f_n}x_2- \cdots -\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}x_n
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The tweak with `\MTFlushSpaceAbove` is needed because of the fractions in the last line. Note furthermore that I replaced `\dot{x_1}` by `\dot{x}_1`.

Comment: Just use `& \shortvdotswithin{=} ` with no ``\\`` at the end, then it uses even less space

Comment: @daleif I had tried it, but it felt too tight to me. But I can add it out of completeness.

Comment: I upvote you also for my previous errors :-)+1.

Answer (score 3):

A tabular stack could work here, in lieu of `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}% Horz. gap between columns
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}% Vert. baselineskip between rows
\TABbinary% apply {} before and after each cell to set proper = spacing
\tabularCenterstack{rcl}{
\dot{x}&=&x_1 \\
\dot{x_1}&=&x_2 \\
&\vdots&}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use the `array` environment:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{c @{\thickspace}c @{\thickspace}c l}
        \dot{x} &= & x_{1} & \\
        \dot{x}_{1} &= & x_{2} & \\
        &\vdots& \\
        \dot{x}_n &= & - & \hspace{-3mm} \frac{f_0}{f_n} x_1  -\frac{f_1}{f_n}x_2- \cdots -\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}x_n
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now it is handling appropriately by doing further customizations to the columns.

Comment: the first minus sign in the last line should be a unary minus.  you can tidy that up by wrapping that minus in braces.